# Does having the mob attack you cause your gathering to fail?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Earlier today, I was gathering an Orrian Sapling which should yield Ancient Wood Logs, the highest tier wood. At the time I was gathering it I was being attacked by 2 risens. I got two ruined logs which typically occur when you use a lower tier logging axe. I immediately stopped gathering. I typically have one mithril and one orichalcum gathering tool of each type. I would switch accordingly when I gathered (to save on costs). I had originally thought I had the wrong logging  axe equipped. So I killed the two risen and went to my inventory to equip my Orichalcum logging axe, only to find that it was already equipped. I used the logging axe again to gather the last piece of Ancient Wood Log which did work.

I know that I have successfully gathering material in the past while being attacked by the mob.

So my question is, does having the mob attack you while you are gathering sometimes cause you to fail at gathering. Or is there a small random chance of you failing to gather a material regardless if you have the correct tier or higher gathering tool?

Answer (score 4):

Mobs attacking do affect your gathering. I tested this out and had ruined logs when I was being attacked. This was done more than 3 times and each time I was being attacked yielded  the same results.  Not once had I failed when not being attacked. I always use Orchichlum for gathering

Comment: This was a bug that was fixed several months ago and is no longer true.

Answer (score 3):

Since both existing answers talk about tool quality, which is unrelated to the problem, and the answer that was correct when given is now incorrect, I'll provide an updated answer. There used to be a bug that caused players who were not in combat to switch from their gathering tools to their weapons if an enemy attacked them while they were gathering. This caused the gathering to act as if an insufficient quality tool was used. This bug was fixed around the beginning of 2013.

**When the question was asked: Yes, being attacked while gathering could cause it to fail *if* the player was not already in combat.**

**Now: No, being attacked while gathering will not cause the gathering to fail.**

Answer (score 1):

Mobs attacking has no effect on gathering. In fact, I have often run to guarded nodes, mined/chopped, and fled, with one or more mob beating on me.

The likeliest explanation is that you had the wrong logging axe equipped, as, as you mention yourself, the node harvested fine when you confirmed your orichalcum logging axe was equipped.

One thing you *can't* do is change equipment during combat, and this includes the gathering tools. It's possible you tried to change tools and failed because of the enemy attacking you, but did not realize you were unsuccessful.

**Edit:** I don't know if it's a problem with Orichalcum tools or what, but the above can not be guaranteed when it comes to max-tier nodes (i.e., Orichalcum, Ancient, Omnomberries, etc.)

Comment: Ok so it just happened again. This time I know for a fact that it wasn't a mistake on my part. I was chopping a Cypress Sapling with a mithril logging axe and I got 2 Elder Wood Logs and 2 Ruined Logs at the same node without stopping the chopping at all. And I was being attacked by 4 risens this time.

Comment: @Jay Don't know what to tell you, then. I've never had an issue with harvesting while being attacked.

Comment: @jay I have a feeling it is a bug with the system with regards to logging specifically. I have got ruined logs from the first few tier trees in the lower zones while using a master logging axe. The master mining picks have no problems even with ores up till mithril.

Comment: @TerryChia Master level tools have varying degrees of quality, they can be equivalent to Iron, Steel, or whatever tool. The actual quality is hidden and you have to experiment to determine which quality that tool really has. So if you fail a harvest with a Master tool, then it was simply of insufficient quality.

Comment: @Hackworth Well, not experiment so much as keep track of. You get 3 from your personal story. The first is Iron, the Second is Mithril, and the third is Ori.